# what to do when the question is so trivial/RTFM that it doesn't even have a proper duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Note: I rollbacked the edit from RTM to RTFM because everyone knows what RTFM is (as long as you don't say "read the full manual" loud, it's fine).

The context is this homework question:

[Python Set Operations without using loops (for and while) or if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566201/python-set-operations-without-using-loops-for-and-while-or-if)

The answer to this question is to use `set.intersection` on set #1 passing set #2 as argument. OP knows that the result must be a `set`, and looking up Python documentation, one of the key features is `intersection`

So I wanted to hammer-close as duplicate (and I did) but the duplicate I used ([Best way to find the intersection of multiple sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/best-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets)) is slightly too complex/more general (because it explains how to perform n-set intersection, original OP knowing perfectly how to perform intersection between 2 sets).

Even after all those years, I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this trivial RTFM question (the duplicate I linked to was also a RT-you-know-what question, but requiring reading more than 2 lines of the documentation, so...)

The question has been answered and answer is accepted, but was I right to choose a more complex/general case duplicate? or should have just closed as "unclear" with a RT-whatever comment?

What to do when encountering this kind of question?

Comment: Maybe use this simpler question as the preferred dupe for future cases, or offer the simple case as an answer on the complex dupe.

Comment: I usually toss a coin between 'Unclear' [why the textbooks, online tutorials and 'Computer 101' courses were not adequate to answer your question]  and 'Off-topic' [Asking to recommend a tutorial].  Neither close-reason is a good fit, but SO will never add a close-reason for 'OP is too incompetent to effectively program compuiters and needs basic tuition that SO is ill-equipped to provide' :(   Do not add any kind of comment, at all, ever.

Comment: @MartinJames let's add a new close reason "Unclear _why_ you're asking"

Comment: @rene can't do the other way. This current question & its answer doesn't solve the more complex one

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: Hopefully you're being facetious but I'm sure that close reason would go over very well...

Comment: I may write a feature request about it then :)

Comment: I think the question is too broad... what part of defining a function with arguments doesn't OP understand? I can't see any attempt to figure out the conceptual / syntax misunderstanding.

Comment: In cases like that I lament the loss of the "Lacks minimal understanding" close reason. I tend to go for "unclear" why you even need to ask this, or sometimes "too broad" because you're effectively asking for chapter 1 of a tutorial on the language.

Comment: For RTM questions, Stack overflow should build a new feature where we could put good example based on the documentation that we could then linked that question to. We could call it Documentation...

Comment: To the person who bowdlerized this, "RTFM" is a well-known acronym: "RTM" I've never even seen before. You don't need to spell it out, but the "F" is actually relevant for understanding here.

Comment: It probably does have a duplicate (if not dozens), but the duplicate is so poorly written/titled that no one will ever find it.

Comment: @Leushenko: agreed. RTFM is good. If anyone asks, it is the abbreviation of "Read The Fine Manual". It's important that the manual is fine. If it is not, the manual has to be improved first.

Comment: @Leushenko I completely disagree with you. I saw this post earlier with the edit to RTM applied, understood what it meant immediately, and was glad to see that instead of the other version. I find the four letter one **extremely** rude, which I thought this site tries to avoid (seeing as "rude or abusive" is a flag reason).

Comment: Opening myself up for criticism here but I don't think a question should be closed for being too simple or trivial. What seems trivial for one person could be difficult for another, especially when first starting out. Is there a rule here against posting easy questions? Although the answer may be easy once known; stating it properly in a question may be difficult. Having said that the question referenced appears to be lazy/homework but could it be tidied up to become a decent reference on how to perform an `intersection` operation on `set`s in Python? Sure downvote it; but don't just close it.

Comment: @Jo. "Birds of a feather flock together", as it were. Glad to see that someone agreed with me though. Real odd though how a moderator being present in the question just let it ride. So "RTFM" is OK for posting questions but don't ever dare to put that in a comment though, that's when everybody comes after you and the mods. To think they're trying to justify this. I personally think that it should have been worded differently.

Answer (score 12):

The question you linked is a question I maybe would consider to close for too broad or unclear, but I'm not completely sure. (Didn't read it to carefully either, since it's not so relevant to your actual question)

But disregard that, and let us consider a hypothetical question, that is neither too broad or unclear, and that it is not a candidate to be closed for other reasons, but still fulfills what you are stating: That is is extremely trivial and could be solved in one minute if you read the documentation, and also that you cannot find a proper duplicate.

Well, then this is the duplicate you should use the next time this happens. Don't vote to close. Downvote it for no research if you want, but don't close it. And since it seems to be a candidate for the primary duplicate for similar questions, consider improving the question a bit if there are room for improvement.

And just to specifically answer the question in the title:

> What to do when the question is so trivial/RTM that it doesn't even have a proper duplicate?

This question is wrong. The fact that it is so trivial is not the reason that it does not have a duplicate. There are millions of questions that proves this assumption wrong. Just to mention an example, every week I see a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) question where the underlying problem is how to compare string, and comparing strings is something I consider even more trivial than set operations.

Comment: how is it too broad? It can be answered unambiguously with a one-liner. And I'm the worst Python developer, and even I understood the question and could have answered it with 1min of googling (I wasn't sure if the method is called `intersect`, `intersection` or `minus`) - how is the question "unclear"?

Comment: Agreed; OP may be lazy, but there are no rules here against asking questions that are too easy. That's what downvoting is for.

Comment: @Michael I addressed that issue

Answer (score 2):

IMO, your actual action taken is appropriate.

When an answer (to the dupe source) contains enough information or details to cover the question, you can close it with the dupe source chosen.

IMO it's appropriate because

- Answers under the dupe source is comprehensive, and fully covers the question to be closed
- The comprehensiveness of the dupe source answers is not redundant. The (source) answers are closely related to the pending-close question, and the extra information than it's needed to answer this one would be a nice add-on instead of unnecessary verbosity.

---

For point 2, in case I failed to make myself understood, here's an example:

> Pending Question: How do I add two numbers in JavaScript?
>
> Expected "answer": RTM (operator `+`)
>
> Example answer 1: There are many ways to do it. First you can use the `+` operator. Second there's a jQuery plugin that does math additions. Third there's an Angular plugin that does this. (with code samples)
>
> Example 2: Here's a jQuery plugin that adds numbers. It is implemented this way, the numbers are added this way, and the result is returned this way.

In the above example, a "RTM" would suffice as the answer. There are alternative solutions suggested in Example Answer 1, but they're nice-to-knows, and I would therefore close the example question to the question under which example answer 1. For Ex. Answer 2, it should not be a "dupe source" because it doesn't cover the desired solution, and the detail of the implementation is redundant/verbose in the context of the question.